# how to store a json file in terminal into csv file

Tags: json, csv, command-line, sttwitterapi

I have used the Twitter standard search API to search tweets and I used:

`twurl /1.1/search/tweets.json?q=I%20have%20been%20diagnosed%20with%20depression`

in the terminal.

The outcome is a json file. **How can I store it in CSV file?**

Comment: Perhaps you can use http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm to convert into csv. But I'am not sure if convertcsv offers a web service you can call programmatically...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert the json file you're getting as an output to a CSV file, you can use "json2csv"

You can use it as a module or directly from the command line, and it'll convert your json file into a csv file with column titles and the proper line endings.

To install globally:

```
$ npm install -g json2csv
```

To install as a project dependency:

```
$ npm install json2csv --save
```

You can find more information on using it at the npm website: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv